# Print Rave Report from command line or Using Java

Tags: delphi, rave-reports

I have rave report and want a way to export it as PDF using command line or Java.

Answer (score 2):

Write a console mode program to generate your report and save it as PDF (RaveReport has builtin PDF output feature). You'll then be able to use that application from the command line.

Comment: I am new for Rave Report.
If you have any online tutorial or links for the same, which can help me.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service. We are all happy to help you with CODE you've written and have issues with some parts. So first read the RaveReports [documentation](https://www.nevrona.com/download/RaveDevGuide.pdf), then write some code. Then if you have some part that doesn't work, open a *new* question with your code, and specific question. Before asking, read ["How to ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: command line parameters can be processed by GUI apps, too, not only by console apps

Comment: @DelphiCoder Yes of course, but not very handy to put a GUI app in a batch file because command interpreter doesn't wait for app termination. You have to use the START command with /WAIT which is not known by many users. And of course a GUI is shown.

Comment: Depends on how you process the commands. No problem, when you do it in the dpr and skip the GUI creation. (You might know this, of course, but not a Delphi beginner)